# tar, exclude mounted filesystems (bind), keep directories

Tags: bind, tar, mount

I'd like to backup a directory, keep mounted subdirectories, but exclude their contents.
Directory structure should be intact, mounted subdirectories should be empty, everything else should be backed up, including files. Don't want to specify every excluded subdirectory via command line.

i.e.

```
mkdir /media/somedir

mkdir /media/somedir/share_A
mount -o bind /mnt/someshare_A /media/somedir/share_A

mkdir /media/somedir/share_B
touch /media/somedir/share_B/somefile

tar backup.tar /media/somedir
```

expected contents of backup.tar:

```
share_A [empty directory]
share_B
share_B/somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad `--one-file-system` option did the trick.